# How can I retain / transfer my Windows 7 license files back to the same computer after a reformat?

Tags: windows-7, windows, license

So I have an old Windows laptop that I used in college that has over time gotten increasingly bogged down with bloat / fragmentation that I would like to reformat. I can get an install disk easily, but my problem is the licensing. My laptop was pre-installed with a licensed copy of Windows 7. I don't have the serial number (it might be sitting in a box in a basement, but for my purposes isn't accessible). There are two stickers on the bottom of the computer, one of which has the company serial number and a "Microsoft certificate of authenticity" one which is illegibly faded.

Is there a way such that I can either:

1. Retrieve my windows activation key either from the computer serial number (maybe registered with Microsoft somehow?)
2. Transfer the actual locally stored license files to an external drive and then copy them back after I've reformatted my C: drive?

...or secret option 3., do they just authenticate the operating system license based on some internal ID and I'll still be able to install Windows after I reformat?

Comment: Remove the battery and look underneath.

Comment: Nothing under the battery sadly.

Comment: Try the dup then, lots of suggestions.

Comment: Only slightly relevant but... if you plan on getting Windows 10 soon, I'm fairly sure you won't need the old key.

Comment: What brand of PC is it?

Answer (score 1):

To answer your first question, I have always had success using [Magic Jellybean](https://www.magicaljellybean.com/keyfinder/) to recover keys from Windows installations.

The process is pretty simple:

1. [Download](https://www.magicaljellybean.com/keyfinder/).
2. Install.
3. Recover Keys.
4. Store Safely.

As mentioned by Canadian Luke, this may not actually work for you. I have done this on a number of Dells, and Panasonics. I generally wouldn't install any 3rd party utility like this if I didn't intend to scrap the original installation.

I personally would instead install [windows 10 insider preview](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-au/windows/preview-faq) before July 29th, and get the [free upgrade to the RTM version](http://www.pcworld.com/article/2921034/windows-10-preview-testers-will-get-a-free-upgrade-to-final-rtm-version.html). You need to keep your system up to date though to be eligible I believe - there are a few blocking updates, but we may already be past that milestone.

To answer your second question - this isn't something I have attempted before.

You may also want to review the [Licensing Terms](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/legal/intellectualproperty/useterms/) for your product before proceeding.

Answer (score 0):

Nope, you won't be able to get the key if it's faded. Your only recourse is to use the recovery media, or order another set of recovery media from the OEM.

The key that's installed with Windows from OEMs is likely an OPK - [OEM Preinstallation Key](http://oem.microsoft.com/downloads/worldwide/windows_7/opk_documentation/opk_windows7_en-us_072010.zip). This is a key that does not require activation from Microsoft directly, but will automatically update if it's on the proper hardware. You won't be able to type this key in yourself and have Windows install properly.

If you lost the original disks that came with it (or, if you don't have a recovery partition with the computer), you will need to contact the company and get recovery media sent to you (most companies charge $20-40 plus shipping). You can then use this media to put the computer back to day one.

Once that OEM key has been rubbed off, it's gone. The OEM will not provide you with a new key.